# graphviz on colab - how to use rankdir

Tags: python, graph-visualization, google-colaboratory

Using colab I'm trying to print a graph  "Input -> program -> results" from left to right, but it print top to bottom.
My code:

```
from graphviz import *
gv = Digraph('G', filename='process.gv')
gv.rankdir='LR'
gv.edge('input', 'program')
gv.edge('program', 'results')
gv.node('program', shape='box3d')
gv
```

I also tried (instead of 3rd line):

```
gv.graph('graph', {})['rankdir'] = 'LR'
```

or

```
gv.rankdir('LR')
```

But it returned error messages

Would very much appreciate anyone's help.

Answer (score 4):

You can use rankdir like this:

```
gv.graph_attr["rankdir"] = "LR"
```